# Seeing Internal Server Error while trying to link css file on html file using flask app at Cpanel

Tags: python, flask, python-3.6, cpanel

I am trying to link the index.html file to a css static file.

```
<html>
    <!-- Head of index -->
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/style.css')}">
    </head>
    <!-- body of index -->
    <body>
        <h1 class="title">Index</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the css code in static/css/style.css

```
.title{
    color: blue;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

When I remove

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/style.css')}">`

from index.html the flask app runs smoothly in cpanel, but if exists I encounter

"Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

error. It has been 3 days while trying to fix it. Any one for help please?

Templates/index.html

```
<html>
    <!-- Head of index -->
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/style.css')}">
    </head>
    <!-- body of index -->
    <body>
        <h1 class="title">Index</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

static/css/style.css

```
.title{
    color: blue;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: What line of code triggers this internal error?

Comment: @Lenntror **<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/style.css')}">**
This code caused the error

Comment: I understood that, but when does it occur? As soon as you start up the server or when you try to access the page that renders index.html?
I am wondering what your python code looks like. Assuming you have a `static` folder which contains a `css` folder in which `styles.css` is stored the code you provided does not seem to be able to cause the error

Comment: Yes sir, When I try to access index.html, perhaps are there things linked to .htaccess file in public folder?

Comment: Can you show the route code that renders the template? Just so that we can make sure the issue does not lie there?
Other question: What happens when you run the app on your local machine instead of cpanel? Does the error persist?